# block input textbox for 1 hour

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a question that i try to solve since yesterday.
I know how to block user textbox input that is simple but now i would like to do it during a specific time (1 hour). Is the case when a user enter his password more than 3 times.

It means that i need create a countdown and is the point where i am blocked.
So I tried to use a Timer. But when i debug my program with a breakpoint in the method TextBoxTimer_Tick
this event is never fired.

Here is some code that i did :

```
Private TextBoxTimer As New Timer()
Dim TextboxCompteur As Integer

Private Sub TbxUtilisateur_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
    Handles TbxUtilisateur.TextChanged
    AddHandler TextBoxTimer.Tick, AddressOf TextBoxTimer_Tick
    TextBoxTimer.Interval = 1000 'Every 1 seconde
    TextBoxTimer.Enabled = True
    TextboxCompteur = 10 'during 10 secondes the textbox will be blocked for test
    .
    . some other code
    .
End Sub

Protected Sub TextBoxTimer_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        TextboxCompteur -= 1
        If Not TextboxCompteur = 0 Then Exit Sub

        TextBoxTimer.Enabled = False
        TextBoxTimer.Dispose()
        RemoveHandler TextBoxTimer.Tick, AddressOf TextBoxTimer_Tick

        TbxMotDePasse.ReadOnly = False
End Sub
```

Maybe someone will see what i missed ?
Otherwise if you have some others ideas on how deal with this i am listening

Thanks for your future answers !

Comment: You would need to store, in the database, the datetime for when the user is next allowed to attempt a login.

Comment: Haaaa...yes of course. I start naturally with timers and i was so in this way that i did not think in other way....that is a good idea and really more simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't easily use a timer in a web application like this; you should instead implement a solution where you, at the time you decide to lock the user out for one hour, update a database column that locks the user out until one hour after the current time. Here is pseudo code:

```
bool Login(string username, string password){

  User x = DoDbLookupForUser(username)

  //user table has USERNAME, HASHEDPASSWORD, WRONGATTEMPTSCOUNTER, LOCKEDOUTUNTILDATE columns

  if x == null
    throw new UserNotFoundException

  if DateTime.Now < x.LockedOutUntilDate
    throw new UserLockedOutException

  if x.HashedPassword != Hash(password){
    x.WrongAttemptsCounter++

    if x.WrongAttemptsCounter >= 3
      x.LockedOutUntilDate = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1)

    SaveUser(x)
    throw new UserPasswordIncorrectException
  }

  x.WrongAttemptsCounter = 0;
  SaveUser(x)

  return true
}
```

After 3 attempts the user is locked out. They can try again after one hour. If they get it wrong again they are locked out for another hour. If you want to give them 3
attempts in an hour reset the counter to 0 when you set the date rather than on successful login. There is no need to reset the lockout date to null; as soon as it goes into the past it will be ignored. It can be handy to know if a user has ever locked themselves out and when so might as well keep the data